# SQL Error - Cannot find the object "TABLE" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: sql

I've been banging my head against the wall for a week trying to figure this out.  I have a script that is run during a database upgrade.  I want to alter a column, "Test1", and add a column, "Test2" to a database table and when I run the script from the installer, I receive the above error.  I run the script in SQL Server Management Studio and it works fine.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
IF (SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TESTTABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Test1') <> -1
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE TESTTABLE ALTER COLUMN Test1 VARCHAR(MAX)
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TESTTABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Test2') 
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE TESTTABLE ADD Test2 VARCHAR(MAX)
END
```

Comment: Are you using the same login credentials in the database update script and SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Honestly, not sure, but I'll look into this today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that we are using ODBC connections to make the connection to the database, and it was not allowing (permitting, not sure) the script to change to another database by utilizing the "Use" statement within the script.  I ended up creating a second connection to the appropriate database, and it worked and made the updates to the table.  Thanks!